# How do I add a tab bar controller to an iPad SplitView > DetailView

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5

I have looked for the answer to this on SO, but have not found a good method yet, so I'd like to ask again.

Standard Split View controller on iPad app. I want to add a tab bar controller (with subordinate VCs) in the detail views.

IB will not let me add such a controller.

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the `UISplitView` programmatically, it will accept the `UITabBarController`. e.g.:

```
[splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, tabBarController, nil]];
```

Where `navController` and `tabBarController` are `IBOutlet` and connected to the obvious objects loaded from a nib.